# RegEx to exclude a prefix string?

Tags: regex

How to write a regular expression that excludes a particular prefix string?

Example input: `"Hello World - How are you today?"`

Desired output: `"How are you today?"`

Prefix strings to exclude: `"Hello world - "`

Comment: How do you differentiate a prefix from the rest of the String? Is it always that same substring, is delimited by a character, or is it done by eye?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will match everything after,

```
(?<=Hello\sWorld\s-\s).*
```

Answer (score 3):

How about [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)? i.e. `(?<=Hello World - )How are you today\?`

A drawback is in `(?<=xxx)` the `xxx` must be fixed length (at least in most implementations that I am aware of).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to replace, so `s/^Hello World - (.*)/$1/`. If you just want to match, use `(?<=^Hello World - ).*`. Both regexes assume you only want to exclude `Hello World -` if it's at the start of a line.

Answer (score 0):

What about.

```
(?<=[\w -])[\w\W]+
```